# Why would you use an optional type for a constant with value?

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

Have a look at this statement [from Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH3-SW1):

```
let optionalInt: Int? = 9
```

Why would you use `Int?` as the type for this constant? You know that it cannot be `nil` as you are assigning the value 9 to it? The purpose of an optional type (as I understand) is to be able to hold `nil.` There is no need for `optionalInt` to hold `nil` in this statement. Could someone explain?

Comment: Could you link the page of the Apple's doc where you found that line of code please? This would give us a context to answer more efficiently.

Comment: @RaphBlanchet I found it; [it's used as a single line example when introducing Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH3-SW1).

Comment: Here is a link to the document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH3-SW1
Search for "optionalInt". It is just a one line example but I would expect the examples would make sense.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu You can add a non-optional `Int` to an `[Int?]`.

Comment: @James thanks, I'll try that next time I've got a playground open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a case where you might use it. It's a bit of a stretch, but here we go.

One reason for using `let x: Int? = whatever` is if you have an overloaded function where the parameters are different types only insofar as one is an optional. For example:

```
func doSomething(x: Int)
{
    print("\(x) is an Int")
}

func doSomething(x: Int?)
{
    print("\(x) is an optional")
}
```

If you want to ensure the second overload is called, you need to make the parameter explicitly an optional e.g.

```
let y = 5
doSomething(y) // prints 5 is an Int

let z: Int? = 6
doSomething(z) // prints Optional(6) is an optional
```

I've yet to see anything like this in real life.

As regards the Apple documentation, it's just a simple example.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch, but before we could find a better reason for using let x: Int? = whatever, this is the best answer so far. Perhaps, there is no good reason for it. Apple just illustrated with a bad example.

Answer (score 4):

I think this particular part of the Apples document is intended to simply illustrate the concept of optionals and nothing else.  They probably use `let` out of the good practice to always start with declaring `let` properties/variables and only switch them to `var` if there is an explicit need to change their values.

As to the question why would one declare `let foo: Int? = 9` and not just `let foo = 9`.  Well, I really can not imagine where it would be needed.  Even if some API expects an `Int?` then you still can pass a variable of `Int` type to such API and Swift will implicitly convert it for you.  Perhaps, if you pass it to a generic function and you want the `Int?` version of that generic to be used then you will want to do that, but it's way too academic already to have practical use.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is never better to create an optional when you know the value won't ever be `nil`. Even the far-fetched example in other answers would be better with an explicit cast when needed.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas:

Assuming you have a method

```
func foo(xValue: Int?)->Int? {
  // some logic
}
```

Perhaps you want to define your constant to exactly match the method definition.

```
let optionalInt: Int? = 9
let fooVal = foo(optionalInt)
```

Or (changing your initial `let` statement), the constant's value is determined by a function that returns an Optional

```
let optionalInt: Int? = foo(nil)
```

Comment: In the foo example above, can you call foo with an Int constant?

let nonOptionalInt: int = 9
let fooVal = foo(nonOptionalInt)

If you cannot call foo this way, then AgRizzo has provided a valid reason for declaring a constant with a value as optional. Can someone comment?

Comment: I have just run an experiment. For the function foo(xValue: Int?), if you pass foo a value of Type Int as parameter, it still works. So, AgRizzo did not provide a valid reason for my question.

Comment: @AndrewF. - I did provide you TWO reasons.  You may not like my reasons but you didn't prove my reasons were invalid. You proved that an Int can be implicitly cast to an Optional Int.